# Why does putting a div tag allow this React code to compile?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I found a solution to an issue on my own, but I am confused why it worked and would like to learn more.

I have the following code that has a run time error:

```
class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const foo = [1, 2, 3]
    const jsx = foo.map((num) =>
      <span key={num}>
        {num}
      </span>
    );

    return(
      {jsx}
    )
  }
}
```

To this, I get "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {jsx}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

However, if I instead do this:

```
class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const foo = [1, 2, 3]
    const jsx = foo.map((num) =>
      <span key={num}>
        {num}
      </span>
    );

    return(
      <div>
        {jsx}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It works, outputting `123` on the page. Why do I need a `<div>` tag? Doesn't the `jsx` variable have the tags necessary to insert it into html?

Comment: There has to be a single outer container. I think you can get away with `<> ... </>` but I'm not a React person.

Comment: you can wrap in `<React.Fragment>{jsx}<React.Fragment/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are literaly returning a object

Consider this:

```
class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const foo = [1, 2, 3]

    const jsx = foo.map((num) =>
      <span key={num}>
        {num}
      </span>
    );

    return ({jsx})
  }
}
```

You are returning an object with only one key called `jsx`, with the value of the variable `jsx` declared just before.

Every JSX should return at it's outer most wrapper must be:

1. A pair of tags:

`const Component = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...JSX
    </div>
  )
}`

2. A `React.Fragment`:

`const Component = () => {
  return (
    <>
      ...JSX
    </>
  )
}`

3. A component:

`const Component = () => {
  return (
    <ReturnedComponent />
  )
}`

Answer (score 0):

When returning anything in jsx, it can only return one element.
When returning only {jsx}, you are returning multiple span elements, which is not allowed.