# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, promise, es6-promise

So I am learning React and very basic full stack web development and I keep hitting this promise when I am trying to get an array of objects in my Mongodb.  Through Postman I know it is returning what I want [{},{},...].  But when I try to use it in my component to map the names  I keep getting

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

On my web console my list is displaying as a Promise  but with the array I want inside of it.  I keep trying different setups with my promise, like many posts on here say, to get it to resolve but everything I've tried does not change this outcome.

```
const ArticlesListPage = async () => {

    let testResult = function()
    {
        return fetch('/api/articles-list').then(result => {return result});
    };


    let results = testResult();
    results.then(function(res){
        console.log(res.json());
    })

}

export default ArticlesListPage;
```

And the component:

````
const ArticlesList = ({articles}) => (

    <>
        {articles.map((article, key) => (
            <Link className="article-list-item" key={key} to={`/article/${article.name}`}>
                <h3>{article.title}</h3>
                <p>{article.content[0].substring(0,150)}...</p>
            </Link>
        ))}
    </>
);

export default ArticlesList;```
````

Comment: `.then(result => {return result})` - smells like you are trying to turn an asynchronous result into one that is synchronous - you can't do that

Comment: another problem of course is that `ArticlesListPage` returns a Promise that resolves to `undefined` - since you don't return anything from that async function

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning a `Promise` and a `React Component` can only return JSX. Refer to this issue for detailed info:

[Why does putting a div tag allow this React code to compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836571/why-does-putting-a-div-tag-allow-this-react-code-to-compile/60837501#60837501)

Here is the part thats wrong, the fetch returning:

`return fetch('/api/articles-list').then(result => {return result});`

The page (because is a `React Component`) cannot return a `fetch`